# Automatically forward specific WhatsApp group messages as SMS

Tags: sms, whatsapp-messenger

I learn in a school, where a large portion of the students don't use smartphones (because of addictions, pornography, and so on).

My classmates and I have a WhatsApp group, and sometimes we send important messages, which the smartphone-less students don't know about.

Is it possible to have a code that you write at the start of an important message (something like "important message" or emojis that nobody uses like ), and the message will be copied and sent to the smartphone-less guys?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is really impossible per say unless not allowed; restriction may be the veil that may prevent such a process and or action.